# Assessment & Planning Toolkit

Tags: virtualization

Is there any free tool assessment & planning for Server Consolidation, Performance counters in open source or free to use.

Comment: What kind of consolidation are you talking about? I see the tag "virtualization", is this your (main) plan? And if you're planning on virtualization, are you going with VMWare, Microsoft, or else...?

Comment: Basically i'm looking physical server performance whether is over load with services/RAM utilizations and it should work with Microsoft server as well Linux Server both os.

Comment: did u try MAP tool? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, every planning tool I've ever seen has been based on Excel.

Typical factors may include:

- current CPU load per server
- what's running on each server
- current hardware of each server
- expected percentage increase in usage
- OS usage - homogenous or heterogeneous
- new hardware or re-use current hardware
- storage needs
- vendor for virtualization (VMware, Microsoft, Xen)

And don't forget the all-important:

- *BUDGET*

My experience is all related around VMware, but what I've seen and used in the past is the following:

- look at all CPU utilizations currently
- add those average and peak percentages in two separate columns
- plan for ~10% overhead from your hypervisor of choice
- for every 40% of 'average' or 80% of 'peak', use one server of the type you now consider "high-end"

  - ie, if you have a total of 687% of 'peak', you need 9 physical servers running your hypervisor of choice

Other thoughts:

- I like to plan for 1 full spare physical server per ~6, so that I can utilize Vmware's Vmotion for migrating servers around
- plan for buying/utilizing SAN storage of some form so your VMs can be moved to different physical servers easily

I'm sure VARs have all sorts of fancy interfaces or pre-built spreadsheets for this, but they also charge you an arm and a leg to get their advice :)