# how to calculate workloads for VM environment?

Tags: storage, vmware-esx, performance-monitoring

typical workloads in a VM environment like: disk perf (read, write), CPU usage etc to decide on server sizing and design of network, disk subsystems.
any tools that help in this exercise?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/58393/assessment-planning-toolkit/66650#66650

Answer (score 1):

Platespin/Novell's [Recon](http://www.novell.com/products/recon/)

tool is a good tool for this.